# C++ SQLite3 prepared delete statement not working

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I have a C++ application which loops through a SQLite3 database. Each row contains an ID which is checked against a vector. If the ID in the DB is not present in the vector, it should be deleted with a prepared statement. I use the following code, however the ID's won't get deleted. I Neither can get an error message from the `sqlite3_step(stmt2)` function.

```
//SETTINGS["Reference"] CONTAINS THE REFERENCE FOR THE ID's (IT's 1 FOR UNDERNEATH EXAMPLE)


vector<int> IDs; //THIS VECTOR CONTAINS THE ID's IN MY APPLICATION
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT ID FROM Files WHERE Reference=?", -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, Settings["Reference"].c_str(), Settings["Reference"].length(), 0);
CheckDBError(rc);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_stmt* stmt2;
int rc2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "DELETE FROM Files WHERE ID=? AND Reference=?", -1, &stmt2, 0);
CheckDBError(rc2);
while(rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
    string IDToCheck = NumberToString(sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 0));
    if (std::find(IDs.begin(), IDs.end(), IDToCheck) == IDs.end()) { //VERIFY AGAINST VECTOR WORKS AS EXPECTED

        //I GET HERE WITH ALL MY ID's I HAVE CHECKED THAT ALREADY :)

        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt2, 1, IDToCheck.c_str(), IDToCheck.length(), 0);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt2, 2, Settings["Reference"].c_str(), Settings["Reference"].length(), 0);
        rc2 = sqlite3_step(stmt2);

        //CAN'T GET ANY ERROR MESSAGE (SO QUERY IS FINE, WHICH SEEMS LIKE IT?)

        }
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You must not call the `finalize` function **before** the `while` block, because that way you finalize your statement before using it. As per [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) (emphasis mine):

> It is a **grievous error for the application to try to use a prepared
>   statement after it has been finalized**. Any use of a prepared statement
>   after it has been finalized **can result in undefined and undesirable
>   behavior** such as segfaults and heap corruption.

Comment: Wauw, I didn't see this... This will be a copy-error. Thanks a lot for your good eyes :)

Comment: I have removed that line, however it is still not deleting any rows?

Comment: Here are a couple of thoughts: try using a statement for each record and to compile it without parameters (for debugging purposes only); if it works then you might have a problem with your parameter handling. Another thing is that you're mixing integers and strings for your IDs. I'd stick to integers for SQLite calls too, unless you have a particular reason to do otherwise.